# Hide featured image from post [Tesseract]

Tags: wordpress, hide, thumbnails

I would like to hide featured images from all posts. I tried *Hide feautered image* plug-in. Also some formulas from similar posts like:

```
.blog .entry-thumbnail { display: none; }
```

but it doesn't work.

My content single file is bellow:

```
<?php
/**

 * @package Tesseract

 */
?>

<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

<?php $featImg_pos = get_theme_mod('tesseract_blog_featimg_pos'); 
    if ( has_post_thumbnail() && ( !$featImg_pos || ( $featImg_pos == 'above' ) ) ) 
        tesseract_output_featimg_blog(); ?>
    <?php //if ( my_theme_show_page_header() ) : ?>

        <header class="entry-header">

            <?php the_title( '<div id="blogpost_title"><h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1></div>' ); ?>

            <?php

            $postDate = get_theme_mod('tesseract_blog_date');

            if ( $postDate == 'showdate' ) { ?>

                <span><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i><?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?></span>

            <?php } ?>

            <?php

            $postAuthor = get_theme_mod('tesseract_blog_author');

            if ( $postAuthor == 'showauthor' ) { ?>

                <span><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i><?php the_author(); ?></span>

            <?php } ?>

            <?php

            $mypostComment = get_theme_mod('tesseract_blog_comments');

            if ( ( $mypostComment == 'showcomment' ) && ( comments_open() ) ) { ?>

                <span><i class="fa fa-comments-o" aria-hidden="true"></i><?php //comments_number('(No Comments)', '(1 Comment)', '(% Comments)' );?><?php comments_popup_link(
    'No comments exist',  '1 comment', '% comments'); ?></span>

            <?php }

            ?>

        </header><!-- .entry-header -->

    <?php //endif; ?>

    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() && ( $featImg_pos == 'below' ) ) 

        tesseract_output_featimg_blog(); ?>

    <div class="entry-content">

        <div class="entry-meta">

            <?php tesseract_posted_on(); ?>

        </div><!-- .entry-meta -->

        <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() && ( $featImg_pos == 'left' ) ) { ?>

        <div class="myleft">

        <?php tesseract_output_featimg_blog(); ?>

        <?php the_content(); ?>

        <?php the_tags()?>

        </div>

        <?php } elseif ( has_post_thumbnail() && ( $featImg_pos == 'right' ) ){ ?>

        <div class="myright">

        <?php  tesseract_output_featimg_blog(); ?> 

        <?php the_content(); ?>

        <?php the_tags()?>

        </div>

        <?php } else { ?>

        <?php the_content(); ?>

        <?php } ?>

        <?php    
            wp_link_pages( array(

                'before' => '<div class="page-links">' . __( 'Pages:', 'tesseract' ),

                'after'  => '</div>',

            ) );

        ?>

    </div><!-- .entry-content -->
</article><!-- #post-## -->
```

It is quite complicated, so do you guys know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try commenting out the lines that say `tesseract_output_featimg_blog();`, so this:

```
<?php  tesseract_output_featimg_blog(); ?>
```

becomes this:

```
<?php /* tesseract_output_featimg_blog(); */ ?>
```

I see 4 occurrences, and it looks like they're related to different featured image positions in the theme.

*As a side note, changing your theme files isn't recommended unless you're doing it within a child theme.*

Comment: Excellent! Again, be careful modifying these theme files, I highly recommend copying them to a child theme. That way you can make all the modifications you want in a controlled area. If you don't, all these changes will evaporate when your theme gets updated.

Answer (score 0):

Some themes give their users an option to choose if they really want to use a featured image for their post. If you have just started with your blog/website I would rather suggest to search for one such wordpress theme.

Also, in agreement with @Jonathan I would also suggest NOT to play around with your theme files. I tried changing theme files a couple of days ago, for the same reason as you have, and ultimately ended up breaking my theme code. As a result, I was unable to login to my blog. So, better be careful.

Comment: Thanks :) I have a backup of every single file so even if something goes wrong I can undo this.